# @app.route not working without redirection

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

This function is working perfectly if I do a redirect to another page @app.route('/results') but I'm struggling to make it work in the same page without reloading :

```
@app.route('/')
def static_file():
    return app.send_static_file('index.html')

@app.route('/')
def results():
    headers = {
        'X-ApiKey': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    }

    data = {'data': request.args.get('data')}

    results = requests.post('https://apiv2.indico.io/personality', headers=headers, data=data)
    return results.text
```

I'd like to display the results of the api call in the same page (below the input box)

```
<form action="" onsubmit="return false";>
  <strong> Try It <br><br>
  </strong><br>
  <input type="text" name="data"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" onclick="showResults();">
        <label id:Results>Your Result: </label>
        <p><span id='display'></span></p>
    </form>
```

I've also added some JS:

```
 <script language="JavaScript">
    function showResults() {
        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = 
                    document.getElementById("Results").value;
    }
  </script>
```

What's wrong with my code? I'm using Flask framework.

Comment: When I use @app.route('/result') I got the the api result (Json) in an empty page, I'd like to get this output in the same page (index). I've tried Jquery and Ajax. All the examples I found on google use a different type of forms or display the (user_input)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, what you want to achieve is to have RESTful API written in Flask microframework, which would allow you to obtain some results and display on your page without reloading. If so, your approach is wrong.

Firstly, you can't route multiple functions with common URL:

```
@app.route('/common_route')
def foo():
    pass
@app.route('/common_route')
def bar():
    pass
```

It is impossible to determine which function did you want to be invoked if you load http://yourwebsite/common_route.

In order to avoid page reloading, you should rather use Flask-RESTful module and implement an API for obtaining results.

```
import flask-restful
class Results(Resource):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Results)
    #for GET requests
    def get(self):
        #your code here
        pass
    #for POST requests
    def post(self):
        #your code here
        pass

api = Api(app)
api.add_resource(Results(),'/api/results')
```

Then you can obtain your results f.e. with JS & jQuery code: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp